# "rhc setup" throws the following error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, openshift, openshift-client-tools

```
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/highline-1.6.19/lib/highline/system_extensions.rb:81: undefined method `dlload' for HighLine::SystemExtensions::WinAPI:Module(NoMethodError)
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`gem_original_require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/highline-1.6.19/lib/highline.rb:14
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`gem_original_require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/highline-1.6.19/lib/highline/import.rb:8
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`gem_original_require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commander-4.1.3/lib/commander.rb:24
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`gem_original_require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.10.7/lib/rhc.rb:30
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`gem_original_require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.10.7/lib/rhc/cli.rb:1
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`gem_original_require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhc-1.10.7/bin/rhc:18
    from C:/Ruby187/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby187/bin/rhc:23
```

I installed ruby using Ruby Installer 1.8 version as I'm in need of this version of ruby for the application.

Comment: Having the same issues. Just installed rhc tools following [this tutorial](https://www.openshift.com/developers/rhc-client-tools-install) for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a highline bug introduced recently (https://github.com/JEG2/highline/issues/83) - try uninstalling highline 1.6.19 and trying 1.6.18 or 17 -

```
gem uninstall highline --version 1.6.19
gem install highline --version 1.6.18
```

Comment: Using other versions of highline also throws the same error. Tried with 1.6.18 and 17. Any other options available? I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 sine the application I'm trying to installs requires this version.

Comment: Just tried this solution and can confirm that it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Clayton's answer is almost good. Apparently highline version 1.6.12 is the lucky one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ruby /1.8.7 with highline (1.6.20, 1.6.9, 1.6.2)
I just uninstall the 1.6.20 version
And all is OK now !